# Karma and Angular basic setup - undefined is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I'm trying to get Karma setup to unit test my application. I'm just focusing on my Angular frontend right now to figure it out (I plan on using Karma for my Node backend as well).

I have a very very simple unit test which does absolutely nothing and passes every time. I can verify this by executing my test with mocha on the command line. However, I am struggling to get my test to run with Karma. I am getting a weird TypeError saying undefined is not a function and I have no idea where it is coming from.

Does anyone know what the problem is? I thought this would be very simple to setup, but have been struggling for a few days now.

Application folder structure:

```
karma.conf.js
package.json
/node_modules
/src
 |_ /frontend
      |_ /app
          |_ index.html
          |_ bower.json
          |_ /bower_components
          |_ /scripts
          |_ /styles
          |_ /views
/test
  |_ /frontend
       |_ /services
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'src/frontend/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'src/frontend/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'src/frontend/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/frontend/**/*.js',
        'test/frontend/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-
preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
   })
 }
```

gamesServiceTest.js:

```
describe('gamesServiceTest', function() {

    describe('gamesService', function() {
       it('should pass', function() {
          console.log('WOOO');
       }); 
    }); 
});
```

I can run this test from the command line and it passes:

```
matthew@ubuntu:~/Node/Video-Game-Website/test/frontend/services$ mocha gamesServiceTest.js 


  gamesServiceTest
    gamesService
WOOO
      ✓ should pass


  1 passing (8ms)
```

When I run `karma start` I get an odd error:

```
matthew@ubuntu:~/Node/Video-Game-Website$ karma start
01 06 2017 17:59:57.847:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
01 06 2017 17:59:57.860:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
01 06 2017 17:59:57.862:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
01 06 2017 17:59:57.873:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
01 06 2017 17:59:58.402:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 2KeKaqM6r1COC3ugAAAA with id 3769272
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at undefined
```

How can I get Karma to execute my test? Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT:**

Adding package.json:

```
{                                                                               
  name: videogames,
  private: true,
  dependencies: {
    body-parser: ^1.17.1,
    express: ^4.14.0,
    mysql: ^2.12.0
  },  
  devDependencies: {
    chai: ^3.5.0,
    chai-http: ^3.0.0,
    karma: ^1.7.0,
    karma-chai: ^0.1.0,
    karma-mocha: ^1.3.0,
    karma-phantomjs-launcher: ^1.0.4,
    mocha: ^3.3.0
  },  
  engines: {
    node: >=0.10.0
  }
}
```

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: try to use npm test or if you use angular-cli try to use ng test

Comment: @acdcjunior I added my package.json to the post. You can see all my versions there.